# Why does my main screen go blank if I make an app fullscreen on external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, ventura, fullscreen

I have a Mac running Ventura 13.3.1. If I have external monitor connected and I put my browser window into fullscreen mode (on the external monitor), the main Mac's screen becomes blank. Sometimes this does not occur.

However, is there a way to get rid this nagging functionality?

Comment: Maximize it or full-screen it?  Those are not the same thing.

Comment: I mean clicking on the green circle on top left of application to maximize it

Comment: Green circle is actually fullscreen. It only maximises if you hold opt whilst doing this. You see the arrows change to a + sign. Blanking the other screen is usually dependent on "Displays have separate Spaces" in System Settings > Desktop & Dock though it should default to displaying on your primary screen not external. Check the Displays pref Arrangement to see which display the menu bar is set to. This is the primary [can't test for this on Ventura, no dual display Macs here with Ventura]